# Div containers go on separate lines when the default is row

Tags: css, flexbox

The div containers (1, 2, 3) in the following page go on separate lines even though the default for flexbox is a row. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="BYRqJUSyYxzsJO4gEFJiApfBJVZXEFnNBlZS4o1I">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <section class="px-8 py-4">
            <header class="container mx-auto">
                <h1>
                    <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo" height="50" width="auto">
                </h1>
            </header>
        </section> 

        <section class="px-8">
                    <div class="flex flex-column">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
        </section> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is how it looks on my PC

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJmE5.jpg)

Comment: Where is the CSS ? you added class flex flex-column and expecting it work like flex box ?

Comment: Sorry for that, 

I am using tailwindcss in the project 
https://tailwindcss.com/

Comment: how do you want it the output ? row or column ?

Comment: But that was the problem, wasn't linking the css file correctly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flex-column means flex direction is column

Change it to flex-row

```css
#flexContainer {
  flex-direction: 'row';
  display: flex;
}

header h1 img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <div id="app" class="border">
    <section class="px-8 py-4">
      <header class="container mx-auto">
        <h1>
          <img src="https://logo-logos.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Twitter_logo_blue_bird.png" alt="logo" height="50" width="auto">
        </h1>
      </header>
    </section>

    <section class="px-8">
      <div>
        Tailwind
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    Without any CSS framework
    <div id="flexContainer">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen you are using bootstrap properties so use **d-flex** instead of flex and use **flex-row** instead of flex-column.

And I have also include bootstrap 4 CDN because in my end your css is not working so ignore it if you used bootstrap already.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="BYRqJUSyYxzsJO4gEFJiApfBJVZXEFnNBlZS4o1I">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     
     <link rel = "stylesheet" 
         href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <section class="px-8 py-4">
            <header class="container mx-auto">
                <h1>
                    <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo" height="50" width="auto">
                </h1>
            </header>
        </section> 

        <section class="px-8">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
        </section> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```